# prove there is no integer solution to x^2 -6 = 0 by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contraction-operator

Prove "There is no integer solution to the equation x^2 -6 =0." by contradiction.

I have no idea for this, can I juz move the -6 to right-hand side and square root both side to prove it? But it seems like not the correct way because the question hv 6 marks

Someone please help me

Comment: $2^2 - 6 \lt 0$ but $3^2-6 \gt 0$ and it goes up from there. Did you mean *rational* solution maybe?

Comment: i not really understand y sub in 2 n 3 inside the x. i think tis question is not asking for rational but juz show there r no any integer solution

Comment: Hint was that $2^2 \lt 6 \lt 3^2$ and there is no other positive integer between $2$ and $3$ whose square could be $6$.

Comment: Assume $x$ is an integer with $x^2= 6$. Then, $x^2>4$, so $x>2$. Also, $x^2 < 9$, so $x < 3$. So, $x$ is an integer that lies between $2$ and $3$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume an integer solution $x$ such that $x^2 = 6$ exists. An integer is either odd or even.

The square of odd $x$ is odd (whereas $6$ is even), so $x$ must be even. Let $x = 2k$, where $k$ is an integer.

Then $4k^2 = 6$. The LHS is divisible by $4$ but the RHS isn't.

Contradiction. Hence an integer solution cannot exist.

Comment: ohhh i get it!!! thx very much, i stuck at tis quetion for a long time